# Pic output power on issue

Tags: pic

I m using pic16f877a for my projects I face 1 common issue whenever I do projects, when I turned on power of controller it's all output are raised high for instant like a spike and thus all load like buzzer, light, relay are turned on for at start for very few micro sec,I don't know wht these effect is called and how to solve it

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE please re-read the rules about asking questions. You should edit your question and actually write a specific question so people can answer it. Please be specific as possible, its hard to troubleshoot a circuit you can't see. Provide a schematic with the schematic tool.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely an issue with having high-impedance state on the outputs on reset.  The usual answer for this sort of problem is an external pull-down resistor on the pin(s).